# PDO select from where in array()

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I am listing data from database using "where in" statement, and I don't have problem when my array is short, but I am not able to run this request with long array.

This is my code:

```
$dbc= new PDO(...);
$numbers="1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8";
$run=$dbc->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN ($numbers)");
$run=execute();
```

How can I run this code when my numbers is like:

```
$numbers="1,2,3,4,5,6,7,...3997,3998,3999,4000";
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I don't get any error just my data is not displayed

Comment: `$number` isn't an array.

Comment: See also [binding an array to an `IN` condition in PDO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition)

Comment: @BeatAlex I know that $numbers is not an array but it work for a short list of numbers why it doesn't work for a long one? that is my question.

Comment: Wait, I didn't read this question properly at all.

Comment: why do you want such a big list?

Comment: Why are you now asking him questions are closing it as a duplicate? Bit late isn't it? @YourCommonSense

Comment: Could this just be simply a time out of the server loading loads of results?

Comment: @BeatAlex it could be server overloading but when I run mysql request for every ID separately it work fine but page is loading for about 40-45 sec.

Comment: @YourCommonSense it is bit complicate :) The list is not long all the time but sometimes I need to list at most 4000 users with their id name surname and cell phone.

Comment: did you try "PDO query fails but I can't see any errors. How to get an error message from PDO?" answer from the linked post?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I had solved problem with $in  = str_repeat('?,', count($numbers) - 1) . '?'; but i still don't know why my code was not working. what is causing a problem Ç)

Comment: there is a dedicated answer  on this very problem - How to know what error it was?